# How to show how many objects in the list, with inputting of list name and object?

Tags: python

I want to write a program that shows the count of particular objects in particular list. The user inputs a list name, then inputs the object, then gets the count.

Here is my code:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 3, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1, 7, 8, 9, 3, 6, 5, 3, 4]

list_2 = [12, 14, 13 , 11, 16, 15, 17, 18, 18, 19, 17, 15, 19, 11, 12, 14, 13]

def count_objects(wlist):    
    read_o = int(input("input object: "))
    print(wlist.count(read_o))

getList = input("input list: ")
count_objects(getList)
```

But it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 line 6, in <module>
    count(wlist)
  line 4, in count
    print(wlist.count(read_o))
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Comment: What was the input?

Comment: `getList = input("input list: ")` **returns a `str` object**. Not a list. The fundamental problem here is that you are relying on the *variable name*. Don't do that. Variables are for *people reading source code*, the inputs to your program should not require any knowledge of any variables. Create a *dict* that maps some strings to the lists, and use the str returned from `input` to retrieve the list.

Comment: input was list_1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Juanpa Arrivillaga commented:

> The fundamental problem here is that you are relying on the variable name.

You should probably use a dictionary instead, if you want to map user inputs to some pre-defined values within your program. That can be done like this:

```
lists = {
    # These keys can be whatever you want
    '1': [1, 2, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 3, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1, 7, 8, 9, 3, 6, 5, 3, 4],
    '2': [12, 14, 13 , 11, 16, 15, 17, 18, 18, 19, 17, 15, 19, 11, 12, 14, 13],
}

def count_objects(wlist):    
    read_o = int(input("input object: "))
    print(wlist.count(read_o))

getList = input(f"input list: (valid inputs are: {list(lists)})\n")
count_objects(lists[getList])
```

This is a very minimal edit of your code, which could stand to be improved quite a bit. Once you have it working I would recommend heading over to https://codereview.stackexchange.com to get feedback.

If you really want to access a variable in your code using user input, you can use `eval` for that, but I strong recommend against it. A slightly better approach is to look it up in the `globals()` or `locals()` dicts, but even then you'd still be misusing variables.

Comment: i appreciate that, thank you